# Sqoop MapReduce job is failing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

Running stand-alone hadoop server 2.6.0
sqoop - 1.4.6

trying to import data from MySQL to HBASE

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/WeatherDataSet --username root -P --table EuropeDataSet --columns "CountryCode" --hbase-table weatherreport --column-family weather --hbase-row-key CountryCode -m 1
```

Log

```
16/04/22 01:59:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1461302761955_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1461302761955_0004 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1461302761955_0004_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://Siva:8088/proxy/application_1461302761955_0004/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: null
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
16/04/22 01:59:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Comment: `For more detailed output, check application tracking page`... please check that page

Comment: I don't see any log there.